# UIWebView on top of UITableView - how to switch between them?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview, show-hide, user-interaction

OK, I have a situation, where a user looks up a word in my app. Static information about the word is displayed in the top 1/3 of the screen. The user can see more information about this word in the bottom 2/3 of the screen. This information is displayed via two different views...

The first view is a UITableView showing the users' activities, and the other is A UIWebView which looks the word up on the internet. I have simply put the UIWebView on top of the UITable view, and when the user presses a button, I simply hide/unhide the UIWebView.

All well and good, except that any user interaction is always with the UIWebView, even when it is hidden, so the user cannot scroll in the now visible UITableView.

Is there a simple way to 'deactivate' the UIWebView, thus allowing the user to scroll in the UITableView hidden below?

Relevant code right now is:

```
- (IBAction)pressDictionaryTab:(id)sender {
    webView.hidden = NO;
}

- (IBAction)pressHistoryTab:(id)sender {
    webView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to hiding it, can you try sendSubviewToBack, like this:

```
- (IBAction)pressDictionaryTab:(id)sender {
    webView.hidden = NO;
    tableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:tableView];
}

- (IBAction)pressHistoryTab:(id)sender {
    webView.hidden = YES;
    tableView.hidden = NO;
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:webView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks danh, this is a very useful function, I'm sure I will use it. I have solved the problem which was in fact due to the fact that the webview was embedded in a scroll view, so when I hid the webview, the scrollview was still on top of the tableview... solution: hide the scrollview, but your code will also work.

Answer (score 1):

From the UIWebView documentation:

> Important You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

If you are under iPhone, push a new view controller with the web view. Under iPad, present a small view controller inside an UIPopoverController.

Comment: I don't think the question has the web view as a subview of the table.

Comment: Thankyou J2theC - very astute - I had of course embedded the UIWebView iin a scroll view. Your recommendations are the correct way to do it, but it also works if I simply hide the scroll view, and not the webview :-)